# annotation are not supported at language level 1.3 android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build

i create new project in android studio 3.5.3 with kotlin 1.3.11

problem is this error when i build project

error

> error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
>   (use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)

or this

> error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3
>   (use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)

in source when hold on error show this

> annotation are not supported at language level 1.3

also this error are for files that generate by Dagger

Answer (score 1):

This happen because your kotlin use java 1.3 compiler.
For fix you can add this to build/gradle

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
}
```

**OR**

other way fix for all projects.

1. Open the IntelliJ preferences
2. Go to Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Kotlin Compiler BUT
   Other Settings > Kotlin compiler if Android Studio > 3.4
3. Change the Target JVM version to 1.8
4. Click Apply

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after a while

it just need add this to `build.gradle`

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}
```